# PayPal PDT auth parameter

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, eclipse-pdt

I'm setting up PayPal PDT and IPN for a subscription/recurring payment button.

I'm using [PayPal's documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) to explain the returned parameters, but one of them is not mentioned.

The `auth` parameter is ~87 characters long and looks like this:

```
AHJkv4ukrM7kwTPe7tt9Q.TPnHnUeQWJyNz4WQsMOKhYrZoaPknmceOp-G.voqTJ2V0ODJYC2u1maUdxl9-iBkg
```

What is this parameter? and how can I use it?

Comment: Yeah like "SarmenHB" said bellow it's something which Paypal use it and you don't need it really. You can "identify" users by other variables which are returned so just ignore this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its probably a authentication string that validates the transaction between your site and paypal. From the looks of it, it doesn't seem like you can use it , its for paypal only.